# How do I figure out where the dead-end is in a sprinkler system?

Tags: sprinkler-system

I bought a new home that has a small area of grass on the other side of my driveway that is not part of the main yard about 10x16 in size and it has 6 sprinklers along the boarder.  I want to remove the grass and gravel it.  However, I don't know if I should just cap all the heads or if there is a dead end at one of these heads or not.  I live in an area that you need to winterize so I want to make sure I do it right.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

You've got to do some digging no matter what, so you don't need any special trick for this.  Just dig up around each of the heads to see where the line is going.  Trace the line from end to end to see if it stops or keeps on going.

If it doesn't continue beyond that area, you'll want to remove this part of the line from the system so that it doesn't freeze and leave a leak.  Find the last sprinkler head in the chain that is not going to be removed and swap out the T for an L joint.  I'll leave it up to you whether you want to remove all the old line or not.

If the line continues, cap all of the T's or remove the T's and replace them with a straight piece of PVC.

Either way, be sure to save the old sprinkler heads.  You never know if you'll need to replace one somewhere else.

Comment: From my expereince of sprinkleer sytstem.. i have found many a time where i did what you said-- to find out about 50% the "last sprinkler" actually was attached to a pipe that led off a few metres and was rolled up, and hidden underground for eventual expansion... but years later you forget these things.. hheheh .. +1